# What would be the best ML method for this use case?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Within AzureML, I have a CSV file which contains `2 columns` of data with `thousands of rows`. I'm looking to run this entire file as training, and find a pattern between these 2 sets of numbers, for example:

```
x -> y

... 10k x
```

And after all that training, I'd want to give this one line as the score model, so It'd look like:
x -> ? (Predict answer from training)
-- Note, the question mark here wouldn't need to be an exact match, as long as it is somewhat around what that actual number would turn out to be like.

Is their a ML method (Inside `Azure ML`) that does such thing? Any points would be great.

tl;dr: `Finding any type of pattern between 2 numbers (w/ intense training).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about `linear regression`. This is answer for your question. And here is the link to Azure ML tutorial [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-create-experiment/)